# Big always on database performance issues Microsoft SQL, Ax2012

Tags: sql, database, dynamics-ax-2012

I am currently investigating a performance issues for a customer. This is a ax2012 software related, but I believe the solution should be somewhere in SQL.

Customer has headquaters with DB that contains all of the data for products, customers etc. Customer has many brick and mortar stores and a webshop- all of these have their own retail channel databases. Once every hour there is a background job running that incrementally updates retail channel databases with new data from hq. If the incremental job is not enough (pretty common situation) a full job runs that purges whole tables and inserts an exact copy from hq.

There is a third party company that manages the webshop. Processess are handled in a way that requires product availibility checking multiple times- on cart refresh, new item add etc. When a full sync is running and the item availibilities are deleted the carts from webshop get emptied. Right now I am searching for a way to handle this issue without modifying the standard logic too much and I'm trying to stay away from the webshop as possible since it is out of my competence.

I am currently considering creating a proxy table for the weakest link in the database that would solve 90%+ of the issues. There is this one table that contains milions of records that is included in many many of procedures in database. The idea would be to create two copies of this table. One of the copies would be a production one, the other would be used for swappig. When the job finishes running we replace the "swapping" table with it. After the copy is done, we make the "swapping" a new production. When another job finishes running we copy the syncing table to "old-production-and-now-new-swapping" table and make it a new production table.

I would expect the solution I'm thinking about to work, but I lack expertise in SQL programming. Can anybody give me a helping hand?

I would also kindly accept all the suggestions in world you have.

Help me stackoverflow, you're my only hope.

Comment: This sounds more like something were you should hire someone to help you. For the scope of Stack Overflow, your question is currently too broad.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, we are already working on a few fronts in regards of performance improvement. We started by revisioning existing standard queries (views mostly) and it already helped by 15-20%.